# kotlin 1.3 coroutine usage leads to ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm building a kotlin jvm project from the command line.

The plain `kotlinc foo.kt -include-runtime -d example.jar` and `kotlin test.jar` sequence works well.

However, I just used coroutines in my code for the first time, and the resulting messages led me to understand that I must include the coroutines jar file in the compilation.

```
kotlinc -include-runtime -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.0.1.jar -d example.jar example.kt
```

The attempts to run it, both

```
kotlin example.jar
kotlin -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.0.1.jar example.jar
```

say `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt` , which is vexing because the jarfile seems to hold those symbols:

```
$ unzip -l /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.0.1.jar |grep BuildersKt
     3687  2018-11-08 08:14   kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt.class
     8270  2018-11-08 08:14   kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.class
     3902  2018-11-08 08:14   kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt__BuildersKt.class
```

Recall that `kotlin Jarfile` acts like `java -jar Jarfile`

```
$ java -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.0.1.jar -jar example.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/coroutines/BuildersKt
    at ExampleKt.main(example.kt:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 1 more
```

Without using gradle or such, can someone explain what one must specify to kotlin/java's command line to make it understand how to build or run with access to coroutine functionality? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: are you aware that the library already exists in version 1.3.0? I think that matches the kotlin 1.3 version you use better.

Comment: I can see that continuations are "enabled" via the "-X" arg to the compiler. But, without importing `kotlinx.continuations`, coroutine names like `delay` and `runBlocking` are undefined. If I do only import, I see `unresolved reference: kotlinx` and then the same undefined references. If I add the jarfile to the classpath, references are resolved and the next error is the subject of this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit example.jar's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: add Class-Path with location of coroutines jar

```
Class-Path: /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.0.1.jar
```

Then run: `kotlin example.jar` or `java -jar example.jar`

Comment: FYI: It took me a while to figure out that the absolute filepath (on your computer) to the lib jar file is needed here.

Comment: Surely there's a way to just build it correctly.